# Quickest way to map lookup table to pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame (`DF1`), as below:

```
Col1    Col2
A       1
A       5
B       2
C       3
C       4
```

I would like to map the values to another data frame (`DF2`), which looks like this:

```
ColX    ColY
Mon     2  
Tues    3
Weds    5
Thurs   4
Fri     1
```

To create this (matching `Col1` to `ColY`, to generate `ColZ` using `Col2`):

```
ColX    ColY    ColZ
Mon     2       B
Tues    3       C
Weds    5       A
Thurs   4       C
Fri     1       A
```

Usually, I would create a dictionary from `DF1` (`d1 = DF1.set_index('Col1').to_dict()['Col2']`) and then create the new column (`DF2['ColZ'] = DF2['ColY'].map(d1)`).

However, obviously `d1` would have duplicate keys so would not be possible. From what I know, the next best solution would be to iterate through each row in `DF1` for each row in `DF2` to look for matches and then set the values in `ColZ` that way. However, I'm obviously working with a pair of tables far larger than in the example given and it takes significantly longer than the map method. Is there a more practical way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `map`

```
df2['Colz']=df2.ColY.map(df1.set_index('Col2').Col1)
df2
Out[211]: 
    ColX  ColY Colz
0    Mon     2    B
1   Tues     3    C
2   Weds     5    A
3  Thurs     4    C
4    Fri     1    A
```