# pandas dataframe map lookup table where key is in string

Tags: python, pandas

I know how to [map a lookup table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53381590/quickest-way-to-map-lookup-table-to-pandas-column). But what if the key to find is hidden in a string:
source-df

```
ColA
"Pete eats apple."
"I like chocolate more."
"Orange from Carla."
```

lookup-df:

```
Col1      Col2
Orange    orange
chocolate brown
apple     green
```

should extend the source-df like so.

```
ColA                     Color
"Pete eats apple."       green
"I like chocolate more." brown
"Orange from Carla."     orange
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
d = lookupdf.set_index('Col1')['Col2'].to_dict()
pat = '|'.join(d)
#if words boundaries are important
#pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in d)
df['Color'] = df['ColA'].str.extract('('+ pat + ')', expand=False).map(d)
```

Comment: This is great. I still need time to understand your lines, but thanks a lot!